# React Native: panGestureHandler stops working after re-rendering

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

There is a simple drag animation in my 0.62.2 app. The drag was implemented with `react-native-gesture-handler 1.6.1` and `react-native-reanimated 1.10.1`. The dragged item is an image in a square grid. There are 2 grid or 3 grids in a row to display images. Here is the code to render single image in method `displayImg`:

```
      const displayImg = (img_source, width, ht, index, modalWidth, modalHt, dataLen, sortFn) => {
       ....
            const dragX = new Value(0);
            const dragY = new Value(0);
            const offsetX = new Value(0);
            const offsetY = new Value(0);
            const addX = add(offsetX, dragX);
            const addY = add(offsetY, dragY);
            const state = new Value(-1);
            const scale = new Value(1);
            const transX = cond(eq(state, State.ACTIVE), addX, set(offsetX, addX));
            const transY = cond(eq(state, State.ACTIVE), addY, [
                                    cond(eq(state, State.END), call([addX, addY, aniIndex, aniGridPR], onUp)),  //<<==onUp is method called after State.END, nothign but a console output for now.
                                    set(offsetY, addY),
                                    ]);
                                    
            const handleGesture = event([
                {
                  nativeEvent: {
                    translationX: dragX,
                    translationY: dragY,
                    state,
                  },
                }, 
              ]);
            
            let aniStyle = {
                transform:[
                    { translateX : transX },
                    { translateY : transY },
                    
                ]
            };
            return (
                <>
                  
                    <PanGestureHandler 
                        onGestureEvent={handleGesture} 
                        onHandlerStateChange={handleGesture}
                        minPointers={1}
                        maxPointers={1}>
                        <Animated.View style={[aniStyle ]}>
                        <GridImage
                            img_source={img_source}
                            width={width}
                            ht={ht}
                            index={index}
                        />
                        </Animated.View>
                    </PanGestureHandler>
```

Here is the rendering code to render an image array:

```
          return (
            <Grid style={{position:"absolute", paddingTop:0,paddingLeft:0}}>
                {pics.map((item, index) => {  //<<==pics is an image array
                    if (index%2===0) {  
                        if (pics[index+1]) {
                            return (
                                <Row style={styles.row}>
                                    {displayImg(picPath(item), screen_width*half, screen_width*half, index,  screen_width, item.height*(screen_width/item.width), len, move)}
                                    {displayImg(picPath(pics[index+1]), screen_width*half, screen_width*half, index+1,  screen_width, pics[index+1].height*(screen_width/pics[index+1].width), len, move)}
                                </Row>    
                            )} else {
                            return (
                                <Row style={styles.row}>
                                    {displayImg(picPath(item), screen_width*half, screen_width*half, index,  screen_width, item.height*(screen_width/item.width), len, move)}
                                </Row>    
                            )};                                           
                    }
                })}                        
            </Grid>
        );
```

The images can be dragged around. However after a new image is added and cause re-rendering, the previously loaded images can't be dragged and stop responding to drag. However the newly added images still can be dragged. I senses that the problem may be related the code for pan gesture handling and animation but is not able to find out where the problem is. There is [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398391/react-native-pangesturehandler-does-not-work-after-changing-the-component-stat) about similar problem but is not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `useValue` to preserve the states of the image component after re-rendering. Since `useValue` is a hook and can not be used in condition. method `displayImg` is converted into component `DisplayImg` and declaration of animated variables are moved to the top in component `DisplayImg`.

```
  import Animated, {useValue} from "react-native-reanimated";
  function DisplayImg() {
    const aniIndex= new Value(index);
    const dragX = useValue(0);
    const dragY = useValue(0);
    const offsetX = new Value(0);
    const offsetY = new Value(0);
    var transX = useValue(0);
    var transY = useValue(0);
    const state = new Value(-1);
    const scale = new Value(1);

     ......
  }
```

As a rule of thumb, all animated value shall `useValue` to preserve states according to `react-native-gesture-handler` [team](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1126).